# problem while converting jetstream to react

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-jetstream

while converting vue files in jetstream to react.js files i found # in template tag I think it's related to Laravel component but I don't know how to  write it in react.js component.

in Vue

```
<template #trigger>
<template #content>
```

in livewire

```
<x-slot name="trigger">
<x-slot name="content">
```

what's equivalent of that  in React.js?

Comment: use `props` to handle the attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research i found the solution
vue HAS SLOTS  it's called Named Slots Shorthand
"#" it's just short for name= <template #trigger> is SAME as 
to understand more about slots watch net ninja video about slot Vue JS 2 Tutorial #27 - Slots
and read vue document about slots
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots-Shorthand
if you know react you can pass it through props easily

Answer (score 0):

it would be:

```
<trigger />
```

or

```
 <trigger></trigger>
```

and

```
 <content />
```

or

```
<content></content>
```